# When I do a toString on a POCO Entity I get a DataReader open error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my first time working with Entity Framework Code First and I'm trying to do a `toString()` this way:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string InterestIn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> FromWhomIsFriend { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string output = string.Empty;

        output = String.Format("UserId: {0}, Name: {1}, Age: {2}, City: {3}, " +
            "Country: {4}, Email: {5}, InterestIn: {6}, Friends: {7}",
            UserId, Name, Age, City, Country, Email, InterestIn, Friends);

        return output;
    }
}
```

When I do `toString()` I get this error:

```
'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException'
"There is already an open datareader associated with this command you must close it first."
```

Here I do it:

```
private static void showUsers()
{
    using (var context = new AdnLineContext())
    {
        var users = from u in context.Users
                    select u;
        foreach (User user in users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand it, **why am I getting it? How can I fix it?**

Comment: could you please show the part where you use the `ToString()` ?

Comment: EntityFramework has a concept of delayed loading.  When you try to access Friends, it is trying to load that information from the database.

Comment: @Cory I don't have an EDMX, I'm using Entity Framework Code First.

Comment: @NicoleDesRosiers Ok. How can I fix `toString()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using .ToList() to force the query to execute (by default the execution of the query will be deferred until you enumerate it):

```
private static void showUsers()
{
    using (var context = new AdnLineContext())
    {
        var users = context.Users.ToList();

        foreach (User user in users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Failing that you could also try adding `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to your connection string config, e.g:

```
<add name="YourContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Ok, I've added `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to my connection string and now it works.